# "I love you more than your dad"

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

> I love you more than your dad

Does it mean:

1. I love you more than your dad loves you   [OR]
2. I love you more than I love your dad

   Does this type of construction have a name in Linguistics?

Comment: Context is the best way to tell.

Comment: It can mean either. It is ambiguous.

Comment: I don't know if I want to know  the  context of this statement  ...

Comment: It might also mean "I love you more than your dad loves tapioca pudding." Since there is no definite closure of the comparison, readers are left to supply their own, more rigorously complete version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependant on how you separate the clauses, it can mean different things.This is an example of 'dual ambiguity' and is caused by the incorrect separation of the two clauses. To correct this add a comma after 'you'. Then it would mean that I love you, more than your Dad

Comment: It seems to me that, even with a comma, _I love you, more than your dad_ is still ambiguous.  Consider: "Mom, do you love me?  Do you love me more than you love Dad?" / "I love you, more than your dad."  versus: Consider: "Mom, do you love me?  Do you love me more than Dad loves me?" / "I love you, more than your dad."  Even with the comma, it still relies on context to determine the meaning.