# Does "than" introduce a potential ambiguity?

Tags: comparatives

source: [an FT news article](https://www.ft.com/content/f029ba6a-2b4c-45c0-b423-74089d953173) (paywalled, but [searchable](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The+continent+does+more+trade+with+China+than+the+US.%22))

> Chief among these [obstacles] is Europe’s reluctance to view China with the same existential concern as America does. The continent does more trade with China than the US.

Does that mean the continent does more thade with the US than the continent does with China, or does that mean the continent does more trade with China than the US does more trade with China?

Is there any ambiguity here?

Comment: Ambiguous, without more context. The article is pay-walled, at least for me.

Comment: The ambiguity exists any time you aren't using pronouns. Pronouns will clear up objective versus subjective case. "Joe trades more with Tom than I" vs "Joe trades more with Tom than me."

Comment: @GArthurBrown - I’m not sure that’s helpful.

Comment: 'Than with the US' or 'than the US does' would clear it up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["I love you more than your dad"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/469697/i-love-you-more-than-your-dad) [Is this ambiguous?]

Comment: @GArthurBrown Not always. "I love you more than them" is often used as shorthand for  "I love you more than they do"; nobody (to the nearest 0.01%) would say  "I love you more than they".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's true, but in this case we are talking about what you should write.

Comment: @GArthurBrown _We_? ELU gives clear advice that covers all reasonable cases, or explains limitations.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Then clarify your comment by saying "but this would not be written in a formal context."

Comment: 'The ambiguity exists any time you aren't using pronouns. Pronouns will clear up objective versus subjective case.' Sadly, not true. Often, but not always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is ambiguous, probably out of negligence. Some people do address others as if the others knew everything they know. Also, the context may be so unambiguous that it could make up for the ambiguity of this sentence. But one simple word could solve it. Either:

> The continent does more trade with China than the US ***does***. (the comparison refers to *the trade the continent and the US do with China*)

or

> The continent does more trade with China than ***with*** the US. (the comparison refers to *the trade the continent does with China and with the US*)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the prose was loosely composed and consequently ambiguous, but that is mere speculation. If we go on the face value of the prose, we have:

> Than:
>
> Used to join two parts of a comparison
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/than)

A similar definition appears in Merriam Webster. Applying it to your example means that the noun phrase in which the comparison is made is “China than the US” and therefore that the continent does more trade with China than it does with the US.

Were the intention to compare the Chinese trades of the continent and the US, “than” would have to sit in a comparative structure such as “The continent does …” than “the US does …”.